# From Salesforce how to invoke ext webservice using SAML assertion?

Tags: webservices, salesforce-id, saml, identity, delegated-authentication

We have salesforce connected to SAML SSO(OKTA) and OKTA is IDP for salesforce.

We have a Java legacy system which provides a Web service and it is also part of SSO. Legacy application expects SAML response to get in.

now, in my case how do we handle the SSO for server to server Call outs?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Have you seen [named credentials](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=external_authentication.htm&language=en_US)? they provide the option of using OAuth 2.0 as the authentication provider for the external system. Maybe you can use something like the [OAuth 2.0 SAML Bearer Assertion Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_SAML_bearer_flow.htm&language=en) that Salesforce provides. (I'm aware that the Salesforce implementation for the flow won't help you here)

Comment: Same question on the developer forum:  [From Salesforce how to invoke ext webservice using SAML assertion?](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BPdqIAG)

Comment: Thanks for Your response Daniel, legacy application wont support the OAuth so named credentials wont help in my case. and Yes i posted in developer forum as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be abandoned.